# WPF: What do you call dual windows where you select from one into the other?

Tags: wpf, winforms

OK this is a somewhat strange question but I've seen this often so I'm assuming it has a name and maybe some tutorials on how to do it.

Imagine two listboxes side by side with the first one full of items. You can select some items from the first press a button between them (often a arrow pointing towards the empty one) to select into the other. This usually is used when you are selecting a smaller SET from a larger one.

This is something you see on a regular basis and made me think it's supported in WPF in wome way.

I'm sure I could create it from scratch but don't wan't to bother if it's already available.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try at http://ui.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Danny Is that a SO especially for GUI? Should I have posted there rather then here to begin with? Sorry I wasn't aware of it's existance.

Comment: It's new - a beta, and it is for GUI Q&A that are not necessarily code related (such as UI design). Some questions are suitable for more than once site. This *might* get better answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has a formal name, but I don't think it's supported in WPF as a native control, nor with the official Microsoft [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) (which does have some interesting add-on controls, by the way).  It wouldn't be too hard to build one with 2 `ListBox`es and some buttons, as you say.

Comment: Yeah I suppose it's very easy when I think about it. I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

In our shop, we have a reusable (WinForms) control for this, and we call it a "double list". It's not a great name, but at least we know what it means.

Comment: I have to use it in at least two different window that will probably only have this control in common. So I guess it's better to make it as a reusable UserControl then hardcode it into different windows twice. New to WPF but it seems you can do it very OOP.